# The meaning of "one-off" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

To the extent that contemporary worries
about "fake news" are genuine and identify
a novel phenomenon, they cannot simply be
about sloppy reporting, **one-off** falsehoods,
or even maliciously planted rumours.

[**one-off** means:](https://www.google.com/search?q=one%20off%20meaning&rlz=1C1CHZL_enIR762IR762&oq=one%20off&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.5597j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

done, made, or happening only once.

But I cannot see how that sense is relevant here. What does it mean to say falsehoods are done, made, or happening only once?

Comment: It's not the fake news that's a one-off, it's the fake news *about a particular event that only happens once*.

Comment: @JasonBassford "novel". edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **one-off falsehood** would be a falsehood that isn't part of an ongoing pattern or strategy. We might call it an *isolated case*.